# booting xubuntu 4

Tags: boot

I have an HP stream 13 with 2gb ram and 30gb hard drive. Touchscreen. As this did not work at all well with windows 10 upgrade program I have reformatted and installed xubuntu 4.15.042 (I think) 6 months ago. 
After some upgrade link that I clicked it will not boot but leaves the screen blank with a dash - in the top left corner. The only way I can recover it is to go into the bios F10 or boot device options F9 and then escape to advanced options for Ubuntu where it shows 3 versions:
4.15.0-42-generic and recovery mode.
4.15.0-39-generic and recovery mode.
4.4.0-138-generic and recovery mode.
If I go into the recovery mode in any of the three it then reboots into my screen but then reverts to the blank screen- when switched on again after exiting.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

4.15.0-39 and 4.4.0-138 are Linux kernel versions, not Xubuntu versions. For Xubuntu, you're likely to have 18.10 or 18.04 version.
If Windows is not installed on your computer, you can boot manually via the bios menu and install boot-repair. Then give a try to "Recommended repair". It should tidy your Grub settings.
I would also advise upgrading Xubuntu because losing the ability to boot can be due to a past interrupted upgrade.
For documentation about boot-repair, you can have a look here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you I will try that . When I first tried to install Linux I tried various versions but it seems they were unable to oprerate on 2 mb ram on the HP stream so I eventually installed an older version. I am not sure what it is. How do I check what version it is?

Comment: 2 mb is really low... Do you mean 2 gb? For low specs laptop it is generally better to try with Xubuntu or Lubuntu. I would take a recent version though, they are both supposed to run smoothly even with modest specifications. To check your version, in terminal, you can type "lsb_release -a"